# POSTGRESQL only show the smallest value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that shows movie titles, production years and the number of scenes in each film and i want to make a query that shows the just the films with the least amount of scenes. so ive got this

```
SELECT title, production_year, SUM(scene_no)
FROM scene
GROUP BY title, production_year
ORDER BY SUM(scene_no);
```

but that just shows all the films in ascending order, i would like it to just show the films that appear at the top of this list.

can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use limt ， it just like top in sqlserver

```
SELECT title, production_year,     SUM(scene_no)
FROM scene
GROUP BY title, production_year
ORDER BY SUM(scene_no)
LIMIT  1；
```

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what I was looking for. I kept searching like things "min_value", but this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `LIMIT` clause, e.g.

```
ORDER BY sum(scene_no) ASC
LIMIT 10;
```